# Is there any story or series that bad guy or Dark Side wins in the end?

Tags: story-identification

Right now I'm wondering that , Is there any story or series that bad guy or Dark Side wins in the end?

I don't know any series or story that bad guy wins in the end.

Comment: Are you referring to [Darkseid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darkseid) or the [dark side of the force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_side_of_the_Force), or do you just mean the antagonists of the story when you say "Dark Side"?

Comment: This looks like a request for recommendations, which are off-topic here. Perhaps you could ask in chat?

Comment: @Micah I guess it counts as Story Identification.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté I meant as bad guys or evil side.

Comment: Story identification is for when you're trying to track down a specific story you've seen before, not any story that has some property you're wondering about.

Comment: @Micah Should I remove this question?

I didn't know that.Excuse me.

Comment: @DSaad: Ah, in that case I'd have to agree with Micah. This question is overly broad. There are literally thousands of works that could qualify as an answer, so it's not even manageable as a community wiki. You could try chat or [TVTropes/The Bad Guys Win](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheBadGuyWins).

Comment: Well, the Dark Side _literally_ wins (in the sense that we're speaking about the Dark Side of the Force) in _Revenge of the Sith_ ;)

Comment: 1984 has the bad guys win unequivocally and completely...

Comment: Skyfall. Silva succeeds in ALL his goals (including suicide by Bond after killing M). I count that as fantasy due to ... well, everything.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt - If you read the Appendix to 1984, you'd see that it's actually written in the past tense (e.g. after Big Brother and Newspeak are discredited). The bad guys don't win; http://www.huzheng.org/geniusreligion/1984.pdf

Comment: @Richard: I don't think you can draw that kind of conclusion merely from the fact that it's written in past tense, given that it's not connected to the main narrative in any way. And in any case, the bad guys still win in the story itself. Nobody wins for all eternity since everything is eventually destroyed and forgotten.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt - The whole point is that it comes afterwards. I agree that it's subtle though, but Orwell insisted on keeping it in every edition as well as explicitly inviting the reader to jump to the appendix on the first page of the book.

Comment: @Richard: I don't think that has much to do with the story and everything with the ideas it describes, that a language can be designed as an instrument of oppression.

Comment: @user14111 - The collapse of the party is implicit. How else could someone write a historical appendix (in the past tense) when even imagining the end of Big Brother is thoughtcrime?

Comment: @user14111 - It's written from the perspective of someone **from later than 2050** describing the failure of the state to impose Newspeak.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One springs to mind for me (spoilered for other people):

In Blake's 7

> At the end, Blake is killed by his ally Avon. It is believed that the other allies are killed as well, so the revolution against the federation has gone nowhere.

You can find more examples, and information on the trope, here:
http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheBadGuyWins

Comment: Blake's Seven Rox!

Answer (score 4):

I will throw out the Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy series.  In the end of the final book, Mostly Harmless, the Vogons finally achieve their original goal of destroying Earth in all its dimensional forms.

Comment: Well, the Earth people needed to pay more attention to Galactic notifications :p

Comment: Hopefully this won't actually happen -